# error when creating multiple asynchronous tests with act function jest js

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs, integration-testing, enzyme

in this case I am doing an example project which tries to show a phrase and the author of the phrase the first time the component is loaded and when a button is clicked to obtain a new phrase. The problem with testing is I am trying to simulate the way the user interacts with the application and having two tests asynchronously where each one has the act () function I get the following error:

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:87      
  Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one. 
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88
  Warning: An update to QuoteContainer inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).    
  
  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):      
  act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser.
      in QuoteContainer (created by WrapperComponent)
      in WrapperComponent
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88
  Warning: An update to QuoteContainer inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).    
  
  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):      
  act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser.
      in QuoteContainer (created by WrapperComponent)
      in WrapperComponent
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88
  Warning: An update to QuoteContainer inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).    
  
  When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):      
  act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser.
      in QuoteContainer (created by WrapperComponent)
      in WrapperComponent
```

The test is passing but it generates this alert. I already looked for alternatives such as avoiding asynchronous testing but when doing it the test does not pass, it forces me to put the await in the act.

This example is simple but I would like to apply this same test in more complex applications to verify the correct operation of it. So it is probably necessary to have more asynchronous tests.

Here is the container component:

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState,
} from "react";

import Quote from "./quote.component";

import { getQuote } from "../../repository/quote.repository";

const QuoteContainer = () => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuoteData();
  }, []);

  const newQuoteHandler = () => {
    getQuoteData();
  };

  const getQuoteData = async () => {
    const {
      quoteText,
      quoteAuthor,
    } = await getQuote();
    setAuthor(quoteAuthor);
    setQuote(quoteText);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <Quote
      isLoading={isLoading}
      quote={quote}
      author={author}
      newQuoteHandler={newQuoteHandler}
    />
  );
};

export default QuoteContainer;
```

And the test related to the container:

```
import React from "react";
import { server, rest } from "../../mocks/server";
import waitForExpect from "wait-for-expect";

import { mount } from "../../enzymeConfig";

import QuoteContainer from "./quote.container";

import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import { QuoteText } from "../quote/quote.style";
import { SpinnerContainer } from "../withSpinner/withSpinner.style";

describe("testing quote api", () => {

  it("should render spinner on start", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<QuoteContainer />);
    expect(
      wrapper.find(SpinnerContainer)
    ).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("should render actual component on load information", async (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    const wrapper = mount(<QuoteContainer />);

    await act(async () => {
      await waitForExpect(() => {
        wrapper.update();
        expect(
          wrapper.find(QuoteText).text()
        ).toEqual(
          "Know how to listen, and you will profit even from those who talk badly."
        );
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  it("should change quote and author when Quote Button click", async (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(<QuoteContainer />);

    await act(async () => {
      await waitForExpect(() => {
        wrapper.update();
        expect(
          wrapper.find(QuoteText).text()
        ).toEqual(
          "Know how to listen, and you will profit even from those who talk badly."
        );
        done();
      });
    });

    rest.get(
      "apiURL",
      (req, res, ctx) =>
        res(
          ctx.status(200),
          ctx.json({
            quoteText: "this is an other frase",
            quoteAuthor: "Plutarch ",
            senderName: "",
            senderLink: "",
          })
        )
    );

    wrapper
      .find(CustomButton)
      .at(0)
      .simulate("click");

    await act(async () => {
      await waitForExpect(() => {
        wrapper.update();
        expect(
          wrapper.find(QuoteText).text()
        ).toEqual("this is an other frase");
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks from now